# How to get raspi-config on Ubuntu 21.04? - Failed to update superblock on microSD on Ubuntu. Needed to setup USB boot

Tags: boot-issues, ubuntu, raspi-config

I wanted to do a USB boot from a PI 4. (My microSD card would not boot. Superblock not writable ... see below). I am currently running Ubuntu 21.04 on a Raspberry PI 4 with 8GB of RAM and using zram to manage swap space (hoping to forestall the superblock not writable problem).

```
I created a new microSD flash card for Ubuntu 21.04.  After booting:
First I upgraded the firmware with rpi-eeprom-update.
I found that when ran raspi-config that there were no boot options for booting from a USB device. I then retrieved the latest version of raspi-config with wget.
I made sure that everything is up to date with apt-get.
I installed the raspi-config source with dpkg (note that the wget stored the file in your current directory).
Launched raspi-config
Select "6 Advanced Options"
Select "A6 Boot Order"
Select the boot order option you want, "B1 SD Card Boot" or "B2 USB Boot"
```

I ran into the problem with Ubuntu that the superblock on the microSD card was not longer writable (Flash drive wear?) and every attempt would drop into Busybox with a failed fsck. Running fsck manually did not help. If you are worried about running into this situation you may choose to set up your Raspberry Pi to optionally boot from USB.  Note that the specific version of of the raspi-config was found by browsing the archive shown below.  You may want to check for a later version.

```
sudo rpi-eeprom-update -d -a
wget https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspi-config/raspi-config_20210604_all.deb
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo dpkg -i raspi-config_20210604_all.deb
sudo raspi-config

6 Advanced Options     Configure advanced settings

A6 Boot Order              Choose network or USB device boot

B1 SD Card Boot Boot from SD Card if available, otherwise boot from USB

B2 USB Boot     Boot from USB if available, otherwise boot from SD Card
```

I wound up putting the failed microSD card into a USB microSD card reader and I was able to extract all of the files I wanted before tossing the microSD

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise in futility.

Raspi-config is a simple (if long) bash script to configure Raspberry Pi OS.

Ubuntu has a different structure (so even though it shares some files they are located in different places), it uses different networking and has a different kernel.